React State and Rendering Behaviour Query: Why Does count2 Evaluate to 4 Instead of 2 in the Given Code?
recently i came around this problem statement, where i needed to tell the value that will be printed on the button for the below react code.
    export function App() {
      const [count1, setCount1] = useState(1);
      const [count2, setCount2] = useState(count1 + 1);

      console.log('count1  :', count1);
      console.log('count2  :', count2);
      
      useEffect(() => {
        setCount2((prev) => prev + count1);
      }, [count1])
      
      return (
        <button onClick={() => {
          setCount1(count2 + 1)
        }}>
          {count2 / count1}
        </button>
      );
    }

my initial guess was that the value of count2 will be 2 and the value printed on the button will be 2/1 > 2. But on running it locally, i got to know that the answer was 4.
can someone explain to me why the value of count2 becomes 4?

can you please share the logs that are being printed in the console?

count2 gets set to 7 not 4 after the button click. count1 is what is set to 4.

@OrKeren the logs were:
```
count1  : 1,
count2  : 2,
count1  : 1,
count2  : 4

@NickParsons i want to know the initial value, before clicking the button. when the page has just been rendered.

@2Dfax How are you running this? The logs I get (if running react strict mode), are count1 : 1, count2 : 2, count1 : 1, count2 : 3. Is it possible for you to create a runnable example using something like stack snippets, codesandbox, etc.?

@2Dfax What should happen is that the initial values should be count: 1 count2: 2, then the useEffect should run once and change the value count2: 3.

@NickParsons i too am running react strict mode and got those values count1 : 1, count2 : 2, count1 : 1, count2 : 4. Not sure, why we are getting different values.

@OrKeren i understood the count2: 3 answer. But I am not able to wrap around my head as to why i am getting 4. Can you share your logs once?
If you are getting 3 or 4. (I am using the same above code snippet)

I followed the explanation by Mr. Terminix and it seems the react Strict mode is what triggered the useEffect again. When i removed react Strict mode i got count2 : 3 while when using react Strict mode i got count2 : 4
Thanks for the help!

The hook useEffect is called 2 times in React Strict mode. The initial value for count2 is 2 and when useEffect is called twice, you can see that count2 is 4.

Thanks for the help. I tested the same locally and got the results and it seems When i removed react Strict mode i got count2 : 3 while when using react Strict mode i got count2 : 4 as you mentioned above.

@2Dfax you can mark my answer as the correct one. In future people may have similar question and like this they will find their answer faster.

Running in non-strict mode:

Initial render: count1 = 1; count2 = 2
The useEffect is triggered: count1 = 1; count2 = 3

So, the label initially shown in the button will be 3.
If you now click on the button:

count1 = 4; count2 = 3
the useEffect is triggered: count1 = 4; count2 = 7.

The button will show 1.75.
Running in strict mode:

Initial render: count1 = 1; count2 = 2
The useEffect is triggered: count1 = 1; count2 = 3
The useEffect is triggered again: count1 = 1; count2 = 4

So, in this case the label of the button will be 4.
If you now click on the button:

count1 = 5; count2 = 4
the useEffect is triggered: count1 = 5; count2 = 9
the useEffect is triggered again: count1 = 5; count2 = 14.

The button will show 2.8.
